# preg_split regex for splitting on a range but retaining some of that range as the string suffix

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Working on the text:

```
This is some text
which I am working   on.
This text has whitespace before the new line but after this word 
Another line.
```

I am using preg_split to split on the unicode whitespace and all special characters excluding newline like so:

```
preg_split("/\p{Z}|[^\S\n]/u", $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

The flag is because I absolutely need to retain the positions of the strings.

I would like to have the preg_split keep the newlines with their preceeding word. For example the newline can appear at the beginning of the following word, or even on their own.

Expected output when working correctly:

```
This
is
some
text\n
which
I
am
working
on.\n
This
text
has
whitespace
before
the
new
line
but
after
this
word\n
Another
line.
```

Can anyone explain how this might be achieved?
Thanks

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have updated to show expected output.

Comment: @Drew this seems to be a simple split of `[ ]+`.Wt's so different here

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookbehind to match the boundary which exists after newline character.

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
This is some text
which I am working   on.
This text has whitespace before the new line but after this word 
Another line.
EOT;
$splits = preg_split("~(?<=\n)|\p{Z}+(?!\n)~", $str);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This
    [1] => is
    [2] => some
    [3] => text

    [4] => which
    [5] => I
    [6] => am
    [7] => working
    [8] => on.

    [9] => This
    [10] => text
    [11] => has
    [12] => whitespace
    [13] => before
    [14] => the
    [15] => new
    [16] => line
    [17] => but
    [18] => after
    [19] => this
    [20] => word 

    [21] => Another
    [22] => line.
)
```

Comment: `\n` appears as a blank line.

Comment: The whitespace at the end of a line before newline eg "after this word \n" results in the \n character being its own result when I am looking for it to be appended to the previous word.
Results using your regex (see [21]): http://pastebin.com/z57b701M

Comment: did you don't want to touch the space which exists before the newline character?

Comment: when the line is "foo\nbar" or "foo\n bar" it is correctly splitting as "foo\n" and "bar" but when the line is "foo \nbar" the result is "foo" and "\n" and "bar" when it should also be "foo\n" and "bar"

Comment: updated, now it won't the spaces which are present just before to the `\n` character.

Comment: That works when there is a single space before the \n character, but not two, it needs to work for all unicode whitespace characters of which there may be zero to many.